# Compare two tables with the same columns and report the difference keeping one column as the reference column

Tags: sql, ms-access, compare

I have two tables. Table T1 with the following columns and rows:

```
#A    B   C   D
-----------------
P1   01  C1  1
P1   02  C2  2
P2   01  C3  1
P2   02  C4  3
```

Table T2 with the same columns as T1 but with some differences in the data

```
#A   B   C   D
---------------
P1  01  C1  1 
P1  02  C9  8
P1  03  C5  1 
P2  01  C6  2
P2  05  C8  4
```

Columns A & B together form the primary key.

I want to compare the two tables by keeping the column A as the reference column between the two tables. In my output I want to see the difference between the two tables.

```
#A     B    C    D   B    C    D   T1-vs-T2
---------------------------------------------
P1    01   C1   1   01   C1   1    Match
P1    02   C2   2   02   C9   8    No Match
P1    --   --   -   03   C5   1    Not in T1
P2    01   C3   3   01   C6   2    No Match
P2    02   C4   3   --   --   -    Not in T2
P2    --   --   -   05   C8   4    Not in T1
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Why did you add the `excel` tag?

Comment: I am using MS Access Database - 2016

Comment: I was hoping to get a solution using excel SQL query but I realize now that excel may not be able to help with my problem

Comment: @marc_s thanks for helping with the formatting it looks exactly how I wanted to look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a full outer join.  Access does not directly support a full outer join operator, but we can simulate it using a union query.

```
SELECT
    t1.A AS A,
    t1.B AS B,
    t1.C AS t1_C,
    t1.D AS t1_D,
    t2.C AS t2_C,
    t2.D AS t2_D,
    IIF(t1.C = t2.C AND t1.D = t2.D, 'Match',
        IIF(t1.A IS NOT NULL AND t2.A IS NOT NULL, 'No Match',
        'Not in T2')) AS T1_vs_T2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t2.A,
    t2.B,
    t1.C,
    t1.D,
    t2.C,
    t2.D,
    'Not in T1'
FROM Table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
WHERE
    t1.A IS NULL;
```

Comment: I named my tables Table1 & Table2 - when running this query I am getting this error - Syntax error in JOIN operation

Comment: I don't see any problems with my syntax.  Can you run one half of the union query and see if that works?

Comment: thanks for checking - I tried the query before "UNION ALL" it works. query after "UNION ALL" is the one giving the syntax error

Comment: Just one finding - If there is difference in the values in column C or D the output says "Match" -- it should've said "No Match"

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, or perhaps you've misphrased it.  I interpreted `Match` to mean the record was present in both tables.  "Present" means that A and B matched, not C or D.  If you want to compare C and D values, then it changes the query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In the sample output in the problem statement look at the row # 2. You can see that it's no match because C2 != C9 and 2 != 8. Does that makes sense?

Comment: So "match" refers to whether or not the `D` value matches?  Is that right?

Comment: Match means value in column C  on T1 matches with column C on T2 as well as column D on T1 matches with column D on T2.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for your help. This is a life saver :)   Please fix this minor typo (ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B2) to (ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B)

Comment: Now that I carefully looked at my report I am seeing some duplicate records -- how do I get rid of those duplicate records?

Comment: @RenjithC Just replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION`.

Comment: There is another issue - when a match has been found, we do not want the matched record to be compared with another unmatched record

Comment: In this case I think we need to look at the table as if the columns A, B and C forms the primary key

Comment: This is a different question from what you originally asked.  You should open a new question.

Comment: Tim, I am accepting the solution you provided. All I had to do was to include the condition t1.C = t2.C in the join to fix the issue. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to implement the logic is to start with *all* ids and just use `left join`:

```
select ab.a, ab.b, t1.c, t1.d, t2.c, t2.d,
       switch(t1.a is null, 'Not in t1',
              t1.b is null, 'Not in t2',
              t1.c = t2.c and t1.d = t2.d, 'Match',
              1=1, 'No Match'
             ) as t1_vs_t2
from ((select a, b from t1
       union -- on purpose to remove dups
       select a, b from t2
      ) ab left join
      t1
      on t1.a = ab.a and t1.b = ab.b
     ) left join
     t2
     on t2.a = ab.a and t2.b = ab.b;
```

I prefer this because the logic for the comparison is all in one place.

Comment: Hi, I am getting a syntax error with the following line 1=1, 'No Match' in Access 2016

Comment: @RenjithC . . . The preceding line was missing a comma.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that issue Gordon. I am now able to run the query. However I see a couple of issues 1) Condition "not in t1" and "not in T2" are not getting fired 2) if there is a match for the condition t1.c = t2.c & t1.d = t2.d  where t1.ab = t2.ab - then I want the query not to compare the rest of the combinations.